# converting getTimezoneOffset() into static timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I have the problem of trying to convert a GMT timestamp on some json to localtime for use in Highcharts.  But because there is a lag between getting the json with the timestamp and when the function runs to get the offset (and there may be more time since the timestamp on the json may not reflect the current time) my time is off a minute or two.

```
var dayLightSavings = true;
var lastMinute = "2013-05-16 22:09:00";

function convertDateTime(lastMinute){
    var a = lastMinute.split(' ');
    var d = a[0].split('-');
    var t = a[1].split(':');
    var epochGMT = Date.UTC(d[0],d[1]-1,d[2],t[0],t[1],t[2]);

    var z = new Date();
    if(dayLightSavings){ // IF TRUE ADD 60 minutes to clock
        var n = z.getTimezoneOffset() + 60;
    }else{
        var n = z.getTimezoneOffset();
    }
    var epochLocal = epochGMT - (n * 60000);
    return epochLocal;
}
```

How can I do this so that it gives me a range of numbers that equals a timezone that can be added or subtracted from the epochGMT time?

I was thinking something like a switch case:

```
switch(x){
    case(x >= 0000 && x <= 0000):
        epochLocal = epochGMT - 0000;
        break;
    case etc...
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking, but do understand that a "time zone" is not an "offset", and cannot be represented by a simple number or range of numbers.  See "timezone != offset" in the [TimeZone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Comment: Also, you may want to consider [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to parse your input.

Comment: Also, javascript dates are already reflective of local time, even when you instantiate them from a UTC value.  Your function is redundant.

Comment: And you are using the term "epoch" incorrectly.  Epoch refers always to the zero line.  In JS, that's always 1/1/1970 UTC.  It doesn't make sense to have a local epoch or an epoch derived from an input value.

Comment: Why would anyone ever use something like `epochLocal`? The [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch) is defined in UTC